# Find color profile given CMYK values for some Pantone colors

Tags: adobe-illustrator, color-profile

I have an EPS file created with Illustrator CS2 which uses spot colors:

```
%%CMYKCustomColor: 1 0.7200 0 0.5600 (PANTONE 282 C)
%%+ 0 1 0.6200 0 (PANTONE 199 C)
```

I need to create a document using the same spot colors, with matching CMYK values.

I took those and some others from the swatches, my document in CS6 uses Book Color, i.e. L*a*b (47,75,40) for 199C.
From [this question](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/q/11377/41914) I learned that the definitions changed from CMYK in CS5, so it's not surprise when I save my document as EPS I get a different definition:

```
%%+ 0.0684 1 0.8524 0.0096 (PANTONE 199 C)
```

The document's working CMYK profile is "U.S. Web Coated (SWOP) v2".
But when I enable Proof Colors, simulating i.e. "Coated FOGRA27 (ISO 12647-2:2004)" exporting to EPS changes the definition, but only when "Preserve CMYK Colors" is checked (which I would have expected to do the exact opposite)

```
%%+ 0.0421 1 0.7941 0.0035 (PANTONE 199 C)
```

Even though the export is changed by the proof profile, the values I get when clicking the swatch color after switching it from Book to CMYK don't change (presumably it's using the document's working profile there?).

I tried all proof profiles that I thought make sense but none of them matches the colors in my input file; however, I need to produce a file with that color—changing the input to match the new definition, which would also make all the colors match, is not an option.

Is there a way to tell which profile has been used to create the original EPS file? I found no indication of that.

Maybe a table of which profiles produce which CMYK values for different Pantone colors? I only found i.e. `0 1 0.77 0.16` for 199C, but I have no idea where that definition comes from.

Is there a table for the fixed CMYK-Pantone values old Illustrator versions used somewhere?

The obvious solution might be to just manually enter the values for the colors defined in the input document for mine, but it doesn't include all the colors I'm using, so they wouldn't all get shifted the same way, losing their relative values which might end up looking off.

Comment: I don't understand *why*, if you are using Pantone designations, the CMYK breakout even matters?? The entire point of using spot colors is that they are separate plates. Setting your colors all to spots essentially ignores the CMYK breakouts. If you need all colors to be CMYK, then you would *not* use Pantone colors as definitions (swatches). If you are seeking global tinting the way spot colors function, that can be achieves with process color swatches by using the "Global" option for the swatches.

Comment: How a Pantone color is defined within a file or with a color profile is essentially meaningless. The only determination of a Pantone color is how the color is mixed in a PMS book. Trying to convert a Pantone swatch to CMYK does not compare because they are two separate processes. ... Also some colors cannot be created with CMYK, – that would normally be the reason for using a spot color in the first place.  So, you know your color is Pantone 199 C ... that means you already have a definition of your color.

Comment: I also don't understand the end goal here. Note that you can't necessarily use 'the same spot colors' when printing CMYK. CMYK and spot colors are often entirely different (hence the need for spot colors at times).

Comment: The point is that this creates a file which has both the correct CMYK values if you use it this way and the Pantone spots; i.e. my output should look the same on a laser printer that just uses the CMYK values (ignoring the L\*a*b definitions) as it does from a professional shop that would use the spot colors from the embedded metadata, ignoring the DeviceCMYK values.

Comment: Do you mean you want your laser printer output to look like the Pantone offset output? Or do you mean you want your laser printer output to look like the CMYK output that a professional shop would have printed if you would have given them a file with Pantone colours and asked them to do the conversion?

Comment: Yes, I assume that's how the CMYK values in my input came to be; there's a profile that has been used to create the input EPS that produced these CMYK values, which when printed match the intended Pantone colors. I'm trying to find out the profile used, for backwards-compatibility.